# Can I define injection and surjection this way?

Tags: functions

While reading Russian textbooks on math, I haven't ever encountered such definitions, but they seem correct to me and simpler to remember than set-theoretical expressions usually used to define injection/surjection. I think I first learned about those ways of viewing injection/surjection in a lesson on Khanacademy. Are they indeed correct?

1. An injective function is a function for which each image has 0 or 1 preimage.
2. A surjective function is a function for whcih each image has >=1 preimages.
3. Consequently, bijection is when each image has 1 preimage, which satisfies the injection and surjection conditions.

These seem much easier to grasp, as I had hard time visualizing injection and surjection always mixing them up. But are these descriptions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are correct. 1 means that any element in the codomain has a unique preimage (uniqueness doesn't follow existence in general in mathematics), while 2 means that any element in the codomain has a preimage. These are precisely what injection and surjection mean, respectively.

Though I would suggest getting used to the other definitions as well, for you never know which definition is easier to use in showing a result.

Comment: Any reference on "uniqueness doesn't follow existence"? I haven't heard of it before. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification talks about exactly one object.

Comment: I don't have any reference on top of my head, but we could think of it this way: an object satisfying a property $P$ is unique if any other object satisfying $P$ is identical to the original object. If there is no initial object, then this argument holds vacuously. Though for sure uniqueness arguments become much more meaningful after existence arguments are established.

Comment: What I have in mind regarding this is that in mathematics we don't use "Uniqueness Theorem"s instead of "Existence and Uniqueness Theorem"s (for instance for solutions of DE's). Back when I first started studying DE's I had thought this must be the reason, for otherwise why would mathematicians-who are usually very fond of abbreviating names-not do the abbreviation in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer is a little bit off, but since you wrote that you had hard time visualizing injection vs. surjection and always got them mixed up, here is what I usually explained to HS students:

Let's consider a domain consisting of all the mothers of the kids in the class, and the range of all the kids in the class, and a function connecting the mothers to the kids.

(1) The function is injective if each mother can claim only *one single* kid in the class. 
(2) It is surjective if *no* kid in the range is unclaimed by a mother. 
(3) It is bijective if both of the above happens. 
(4) It is not a function if a kid can claim two mothers, which is not possible in reality, unless it is in a same-sex family situation :-) .

Hope this helps and thanks.

Comment: I think you have (1) and (4) mixed up. Since your domain is mothers and your codomain is kids, injective means that there aren't two different mothers with the same kid. The condition that each mother claims exactly one kid in the class is what it means to be a function.